# Backup and Restore EncryptedSharedPreferences

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, sharedpreferences, backup

I use EncryptedSharedPreferences to store passwords.
According to the instructions at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences, I have excluded the preferences from the app backup. So if someone reinstalls my app or changes their smartphone, all the settings of my app will be restored via Google Cloud - except for the passwords....
If you don't exclude the EncryptedSharedPreferences from the backup, the passwords can't be read on the new device because a different key is used there. In this respect, the procedure is correct.

However, if you restore the app settings on the same device, the passwords can be read without problems.

So I would like to generally include the EncryptedSharedPreferences when backing up. Only if the passwords can't be read on the new device, the user then has to re-enter them.

If the passwords can no longer be read due to the lack of a key, they can't be re-saved either. The EncryptedSharedPreferences can then not be deleted or overwritten. "EncryptedSharedPreferences.create" terminates with an exception.